# In "unittest discover", what does the "-t" option do?

Tags: python, python-unittest

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-t) states that the `-t` option controls the:

> Top level directory of project (defaults to start directory)

Usually people use the `-s` option (`python -m unittest discover tests/` is equivalent to `python -m unittest discover -s tests`), and I have never seen anyone use `-t` before. The brief description in the documentation is not enlightening to me.

What does the "top level directory" mean in this particular context? What exactly does the `-t` option do?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that although the top-level directory defaults to whatever the starting directory is, the starting directory must be *contained* by the test directory.

From the first paragraph on [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery):

> Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages (including namespace packages) **importable from the top-level directory** of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid identifiers).

Suppose you have a directory structure like

```
./
   tests1/
   tests2/
```

If `./` is the top-level directory and `tests1` is the starting directory, no tests will discovered under `tests2`, even though `tests2` is importable from the top-level directory.

The purpose of `-s` would be to discover only a subset of tests for a particular project. The purpose of `-t` might be to choose a particular "subproject" to run tests for.

Comment: I experimented with this a little bit, based on what you described here. It looks like `-t foo` equivalent to setting `PYTHONPATH=foo`. Does that seem right? Or is it wrong, but it happened to work in my particular setup?